# How can I make a session start on the index page if that is where the login form is?

Tags: php, session, authentication

When I load index.php, there is no session started. There is a login form that uses a login class I created, and when the user is successfully logged in, he is taken back to index.php, at which time the session should start.

What do I need to do to ensure that the session starts on the index page only when a successful login has occurred?

Comment: Hi NojoRu. Try to start the session before u redirect to index.php, after you check login was successfull

Answer (score 3):

Session and authentication are not synonymous.  You can start the session without logging it.  You can set a session specific variable and check it to determine if the user is logged in.

Just start the session at the top of the page, whether the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about session_start() it won't set any session it will just initiate session. So you can put session_start() at top of file still

Setting session is rather Simple when you run the login sql query and check for successful result put if condition if the login is successful then set session, something like this

```
if(sussessful_login) {
   $_SESSION['yoursessionname'] =  'value';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting yourself in a catch-22 situation. A login's success would be stored **IN** the session, so you'd have to start a session to check if the user's logged in.

You'd want something more like this

```
<?php

session_start(); // ALWAYS start a session, regardless

if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
   ... not login sentinel set, redirect to login page ...
}
... proceed onwards
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I have.